# rror C2039: 'SetNextFrameCallback': is not a member of 'flutter::FlutterEngine'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

I was running the Windows Build of the Flutter project and I am getting the following errors :

1. error C2039: 'SetNextFrameCallback': is not a member of 'flutter::FlutterEngine'
   2.error C2039: 'ForceRedraw': is not a member of 'flutter::FlutterViewController'

Please guide me how to resolve these errors.

Tried running flutter clean and then flutter pub update but it didn't worked.